# Prove by induction $n^3 < 3^n$. What is the value of $n_0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction for $n \geq n_0$, $n^3 < 3^n$. What is the value of $n_0$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434505/show-by-induction-that-n3-leq-3n-for-all-natural-numbers-n

Comment: for n=3, n^3=3^n. Does this help ?

Comment: @KennedyS It also may be helpful for you to [look at](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)$. It will help you in formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^3 < 3^n$ when $n \ge 4$, so $n_0 = 4$. This is our base case since $64 < 81$.

Assume the result to be true for $n=k$, then $k^3 < 3^k\implies 3k^3 < 3^{k+1}$.

We want to show $(k+1)^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \le 3k^3$ for $k\ge4$.

So just show that $2k^3 - 3k^2 - 3k - 1 \ge 0$ for $k\ge4$.